# Why does this bash conditional check work with [[ -n .. ]] but not [ -n .. ]?

Tags: bash, test

I have a script that fails to detect zero length strings,the script uses `[ -n $value  ]` in a bash conditional expression, i.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

value=""
if [ -n $value ]
then
    echo "value is non-zero"
fi
```

result

> value is non-zero

If I use `[[ -n $value ]]` it works, i.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

value=""
if [[ -n $value ]]
then
    echo "value is non-zero"
fi
```

using `[[` produces no output as expected. From the man page:

> ```
>    [[ expression ]]
>       Return a status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional expression expression.  Expressions are composed of the pri‐
>       maries described below under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS.  Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the  words  between
>       the  [[  and ]]; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, command substitution, process substitution,
>       and quote removal are performed.  Conditional operators such as -f must be unquoted to be recognized as primaries.
> ```

I can't make out an explanation for the behaviour from this.
Why does `[[` detect zero length strings but `[` doesn't?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

this is because `[[` takes an *expression*, and `[` takes *arguments* which it translates into an *expression*.

`[[` is syntax - it isn't a *builtin command* as `[` is, but rather `[[` is a *compound command* and is more akin to `{` or `(` than it is to `[`.

in any case, because `[[` is parsed *alongside* `$expansions`, it has no difficulty understanding the difference between a null-valued expansion and a missing operand.

`[`, however, is a routine run *after* all command-line expansions have already taken place, and by the time it evaluates its expressions, `$null_expansion` has already been expanded away into nothing, and so all it receives is `[ -n ]`, which *may not* be a valid expression. `[` is spec'd to return true for a not-null single-argument case - as it does for `-n` here - but the [very same spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128) goes on to say...

> The two commands:
>
> ```
>   test "$1"
>   test ! "$1"
> ```
>
> could not be used reliably on some historical systems. Unexpected results would occur if such a string expression were used and `$1` expanded to `!`, `(`, or a known unary primary *(such as `-n`)*. Better constructs are:
>
> ```
>   test -n "$1"
>   test -z "$1"
> ```

there are upsides and downsides to both forms. `[` expressions can be constructed *out of* expansions, and so:

```
[ "-${z:-n}" "$var" ]
```

...could be a perfectly valid way to build a test, but is not doable with:

```
[[ "-${z:-n}" "$var" ]]
```

...which is a nonsense command. The differences are entirely due to the command-line parse-point at which the test is run.

Comment: when you say `[[` is a compound command - is that because it performs multiple operations? e.g. does more work to make its use more user friendly?

Comment: @user4668401 `[[` is not more *user-friendly*, it is more *innate*. `[` and `test` were, historically, separate executable commands found in `$PATH`, and so shell `[` builtins were designed to behave as an outside command would. `[[` has never had that distinction, however, and so it has no need to behave as an outside executable might, and it can address names and information the shell possesses as if it is its own *(because it is)*.

Comment: ah right! NOW I see . so the reason for all the quoting and expansion issues is because bash is literally outsourcing the task to another program

Comment: almost right.  `[` and `test` ARE external commands, but many shells also have them as built-ins for convenience and speed - but the built-in versions are bug-for-bug compatible so they don't break existing scripts.

Comment: @user4668401 - not exactly. `[` is a `bash` builtin as well, but it is a more separate routine than is `[[`.

Comment: @cas - not exactly. `[` and `test` are external commands if you have installed them. historically, they always were, and had nothing to do with the shell at all.

Comment: Name one unix that doesn't have them as external commands.  BTW,  both `/usr/bin/[` and `/usr/bin/test` are in GNU coreutils.

Comment: right, but regardless of which version of  `[` is installed and used by bash - whenever you use `[` you need to have the mindset of *I'm calling another program so I need to handle parameter passing accordingly*

Comment: @cas - at&t openast *(which is the package in which you get `ksh93`)* includes neither.

Comment: @user4668401 - that's exactly right.

Comment: AT&T's AST is, according to the web page, an open source software collection, not a unix in itself.  The fact that one particular software collection doesn't include them proves nothing.

Comment: @cas - it is as much a unix as is GNU coreutils. well, it is moreso in that its components are UNIX certified. in any case, are you through?

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm going to accept this answer because I think it addresses the more fundamental issue of *why* the behaviour occurs. Which seems to be that despite recent changes to `test`,  `[` and their implementations, their history is that of separate programs so you need to treat them as such when you pass parameters to them.

Answer (score 11):

Variables don't have to be double-quoted in `[[ ]]` but they should be quoted for `[ ]`.

Without quotes, if `$value` is an empty string, `[ -n $value ]` is exactly the same as `[ "-n" ]`.  `"-n"` is a string test and evaluates as not-empty and thus true, so the test succeeds.

(why?  because `-n STRING` and `STRING` are the same for `[` aka `test` - they're both a test for string-is-not-empty)

Further experiments indicate that this seems to be the case for all single-operand tests, including file operators - if there is no operand, `[ ]` treats the single argument as a string test.  This would probably be considered a bug and fixed if it wasn't a historical fact that script writers have come to depend upon over the decades - and changing it would break an uncountable number of existing scripts.

With quotes, `[ -n "$value" ]` is exactly the same as `[ -n "" ]`, so the test fails.

`[[ ... ]]` is a lot more forgiving about quoting of variables - quoting is optional and it works the same with or without quotes.

Comment: Ah ok, so if `[ -n $value ]` is used - bash evaluates `$value` *before*  it performs it passes it to the `[` command, so the parameter `[` sees is `""` ?

Comment: ah, and hence syntax error - because no closing `]`

Comment: `[[` does not work the same with or without quotes.

Comment: it does in this context.

Comment: not even in this context. try quoting `-n`.

Comment: @cas please clam down. Calling other users names isn't acceptable behavior.

Comment: trolling and stalking is unacceptable behaviour.